# Fibonacci Sequences and Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Consider the Fibonacci sequence such that $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$, and for
all $n \geq 2$, $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$. I Recognize that
$$\left(\begin{array}{c} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{c} a_{n+1}+a_n \\ a_{n+1}\end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1 \\ 1&0\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} a_{n+1}\\ a_n\end{array}\right).$$
Let $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\1&0 \end{array}\right) = A.$

I want to show that $\left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \\ 1\end{array}
\right)$ Converges to an eigenvector of $A$. At first, I would imagine the
best start would be to find the eigenvectors of $A$, i.e.
$$det(A-\lambda I)
= det\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1-\lambda&1\\ 1&-\lambda\end{array}\right)$$
$$= det\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1-\lambda&1 \\ 0&-\lambda -\frac{1}{1-\lambda}
\end{array}\right)$$
$$=(1-\lambda)(-\lambda-\frac{1}{1-\lambda}).$$

If we set this equal to $0$, we either have the case that
$$\lambda = 1 \vee \lambda + \frac{1}{1-\lambda} = 0$$
$$\implies \lambda = 1 \vee \lambda(1-\lambda) = -1$$
$$\implies \lambda = 1 \vee -\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1 = 0$$
$$\implies \lambda = 1 \vee \lambda^2 - \lambda - 1 = 0$$

I can easily use these equations to solve for my eigenvectors, but I am
not sure what to do with $a_n$ in terms of finding a closed-form solution
for the value. Any recommendations on this?

Comment: You introduced a non-existent eigenvalue of $1$; the correct polynomial is $\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0$, and the eigenvalues are $$\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$$ and $$\widehat\varphi=-\frac1{\varphi}=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\;.$$ You’ll find that an eigenvector corresponding to $\varphi$ is ${\varphi\brack 1}$; it’s the one that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your eigenvectors as columns, form a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal.

Then you know that 
$$(P^{-1}AP)^n = P^{-1}A^nP$$ so
$$
A^n =P (P^{-1}AP)^n P^{-1}
$$
Since raising a diagonal matrix to any integer power is trivial, this gives $A^n$ in closed form, from which you can find the limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ rather easily.

One caveat -- if the first two $a_k$ are such that the larger eigenvalue gets no component, then the behavior of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ as $n\to\infty$ changes.